# Sorting arrays of strings/struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm a newbie with C language and I need to make a function to sort an array of struct Student data types (after the element `Student.ime` alphabetically). I am not really sure where to put the pointers so I can return the new array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student {
    int id;
    char ime[20];
    char prezime[20];
    char brindexa[20];
    struct Datum datum_rodjenja;
};

struct Student sortiraj(struct Student niz[], int vel)
{
    int i, j;
    struct Student tempo;
    tempo = niz[0];
    for(j=0 ; j<vel ; j++)
    {
        for(i=j ; i<vel ; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(tempo.ime,niz[i].ime)>0)
            {
                tempo = niz[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        niz[j] = tempo;
        j++;
    }
    return niz;
}
```

The array is stored in a `.txt` file but that is not the problem. One more thing, how do I call the function in the `main()`. I thought maybe like this?

```
niz=sortiraj(niz, vel);
```

Can someone give me any tips please. Thank you.

Comment: A newbie that is able to indent code - this is refreshing and gets a +1

Comment: `sortiraj` incorrect. Why not use the `qsort`?

Comment: have you considered qsort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the `qsort()` function?  Example:

If you have an array of strings say *strings*, (Note: not an array of structs), with the number of strings being say, *cnt* then:

```
qsort(strings, cnt, sizeof(char*), sortstring);
```

With the function sortstring defined as:

```
static int sortstring( const void *str1, const void *str2 )
{
    const char *rec1 = *(const char**)str1;
    const char *rec2 = *(const char**)str2;
    int val = strcmp(rec1, rec2);

    return val;
}

//for a simple test, run this main with the code above:  

int main(void)  
{  
    char *strings[]={"this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "the", "qsort", "function", "to", "try"};
    int strlen = sizeof(strings)/sizeof(char *);

    qsort(strings, strlen, sizeof(char *), sortstring);

    return 0;
}  

//Note my environment required #include <ansi_c.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be sorting the array in-place, so you don't really need to return it at all. Also, use the standard library function `qsort()`:

```
int cmp(const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
    const struct Student *a = ap, *b = bp;
    return strcmp(a->ime, b->ime);
}

struct Student students[] = { /* whatever */ };
qsort(
    students,
    sizeof(students) / sizeof(studends[0]),
    sizeof(students[0]),
    cmp
);
```

Also, please use English function and variable names.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will use english from now on, I just registeres so I forgot about that. I'll try to implement this to my code.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Your answer more accurately and precisely answers the question (sorts array of struct).  Not sure why I got the check mark.  Nice job as usual.  +1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function signature is not marked return type as an `Array of Students`. Second of all, I don't know which sorting algorithm you're trying to use, but your implementation isn't right.

If you correct your function signature, you shouldn't get any error by the way you're calling the:

```
struct Student* sortiraj(struct Student niz[], int vel)
```

tips about your `sortiraj`: Check either `selection sort` or `bubble sort` for your sort algorithm. And for further study, you can check some recursive algorithms like `merge sort` and `quick sort` which are more advance and you need more programming knowledge to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the return type of function `sortiraj` to `void`.
2. Create and fill the `struct Student niz[]` array in function `main`.
3. From function `main`, pass the array and its length (`vel`) to function `sortiraj`.
4. And of course, no need to return anything from function `sortiraj` (as implied in section 1).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing in a pointer, namely `niz`, you are changing the memory that `niz` points to. This means that you don't *have* to return `niz`.

However if you want to return `niz` your function's return type must be the same type as `niz`. Currently you have a return type of just `struct Student` so you should be getting a compilation error.